# How does Kruskal and Prim change when edge weights are in the range of 1 to |V| or some constant W?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, kruskals-algorithm, prims-algorithm, clrs

I'm reading CLRS Algorithms Edition 3 and I have two problems for my homework (I'm not asking for answers, I promise!). They are essentially the same question, just applied to Kruskal or to Prim. They are as follows:

> Suppose that all edge weights in a graph are integers in the range from 1 to |V|. How fast can you make [Prim/Kruskal]'s algorithm run? What if the edge weights are integers in the range from 1 to W for some constant W?

I can see the logic behind the answers I'm thinking of and what I'm finding online (ie sort the edge weights using a linear sort, change the data structure being used, etc), so I don't need help answering it. But I'm wondering why there is a difference between the answer if the range is 1 to |V| and 1 to W. Why ask the same question twice? If it's some constant W, it could literally be anything. But honestly, so could |V| - we could have a crazy large graph, or a very small one. I'm not sure how the two questions posed in this problem are different, and why I need two separate approaches for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference in complexity between an algorithm that runs in O(V) time and O(W) time for constant W. Sure, V could be anything, as could W, but that's not really the point: one is linear, one, is O(1). The question is then for which algorithms could having a restricted range of edge-weights impact complexity (based, as you suggest on edge-weight sort time and choice in data-structure), and what would the actual new optimal complexity be for linearly bounded edge-weights vs. for edge-weights bounded by a constant, W.

Having bounded edge-weights could open up new possibilities for sorting algorithms for Kruskal's, and might change the data structure you'd want to use to implement the queue for Prim's along with the most optimal way you could implement extract-min and update-key operations for that queue. The extent to which edge-weights are bounded can impact whether a particular change in data structure or implementation is even beneficial to make in terms of final complexity.

For example, knowing that the n elements of a list are bounded in value by a constant W makes it so that a switch to radix sort would improve the asymptotic complexity of sorting them, but if I instead only knew that they were bounded in value by 2^n there would be no advantage in changing to radix sort over the traditional methods and their O(n*logn) sorting complexity.